# How to find source of desktop notification in ubuntu?

Tags: 18.04, bash, notification, log, syslog

I find desktop notifications useful, as information from number of services gets pushed right in front of my face. However recently I must have installed something unwanted, because these began to appear regularly:

[image: notification that reeks]


[image: another notification]

Thing is, I don't even have antivirus installed and the notification annoys me at this point. I want to pinpoint its source and delete it. I tried searching /var/log/*log files for phrase 'notify-send', but it yielded nothing. 
My os is Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS

Comment: "Thing is, I don't even have antivirus installed" I would claim you do... and it is named Norton :-) So,... start with a search in Ubuntu Software for Norton and see it it is installed. You might have installed it as a bundled software from some other software. You should also check browser extensions.

Comment: Good idea! I checked and found nothing but I do appreciate it :)

Comment: Have you turned on or accepted notifications from some website in Google Chrome? A family member was getting popups and it turned out to be that. I don't use Chrome and it took me a long time to figure it out.

Comment: Now that you mentioned it, I think I might have. I checked extensions though and didn't see anything suspicious there. I'll try to find browser log if there is one... Any ideas guys? I truly believed it was going to be in system log. Imagine my disappointment :D

Comment: Maybe ubuntu WSL ?